# TAB click moves to next datagridview cell but cursor does not appear

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView into a Windows Form, and when I press right-arrow key, the cursor appears on the next cell. But when I press TAB, the selection changes but the cursor does not appear on the next cell, and what I really want is to make this cursor appear somehow. 
I think that would be a solution doing TAB to emulate a Right-Arrow click when the user clicks TAB in some of the ComboBox/TextBox cells. 
Some of the Subs I actually have in my Windows Form code:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellMouseClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellMouseClick
    sender.BeginEdit(True)
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.SelectionChanged
    sender.BeginEdit(True)
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing
    If IsComboBoxCell(DataGridView1.CurrentCell) Then
        Dim cb As ComboBox = TryCast(e.Control, ComboBox)
        If cb IsNot Nothing Then
            cb.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown
            cb.DropDownHeight = 200
            cb.AutoCompleteSource = Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteSource.ListItems
            cb.AutoCompleteMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
            RemoveHandler cb.Validated, AddressOf cb_Validated
            AddHandler cb.Validated, AddressOf cb_Validated
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub cb_Validated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim selectedItem = CType(sender, ComboBox).SelectedItem
    Dim col = CType(DataGridView1.Columns(DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex), DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(col.ValueMember) Then
        DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = selectedItem

    End If
End Sub
```

It works fine for Enter but does not work for TAB.
Is it possible to be done? The User press TAB but it fires like Right Arrow, or some other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your "StandardTab" property is not set to "true"

If it doesn't work (I don't know why) try handling keyup

```
 private void Data_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
            SendKeys.Send("{RIGHT}");
    }
```

sory for c# code but I guess you will easily write it in vb

Comment: It was set to "False", but change it to "True" makes the focus move to a button out of the datagridview; it stops moving through the datagridview.